# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

```
root@ubuntu:/home/teqlinux/HMI_SCADA/GenLogic/glg_linux/glg/examples_c_cpp/misc/Blinking# gcc --version

gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

```
root@ubuntu:/home/teqlinux/HMI_SCADA/GenLogic/glg_linux/glg/examples_c_cpp/misc/Blinking# type -a gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
```

I am facing some error during build some `.c` file:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/teqlinux/HMI_SCADA/GenLogic/glg_linux/glg/examples_c_cpp/misc/Blinking# make -f makefile 
( gcc -L/home/teqlinux/HMI_SCADA/GenLogic/glg_linux/glg/lib  -L. -o GlgBlinkingExampleG GlgBlinkingExampleG.o  \
    -lglg_int -lglg -lglg_map_stub  \
    -lXm -lXt -lX11  \
                -lXft -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lz -ljpeg -lpng \
                 -lm -ldl -lpthread \
    || ( rm GlgBlinkingExampleG ; exit 1 ) )
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
rm: cannot remove 'GlgBlinkingExampleG': No such file or directory
makefile:126: recipe for target 'GlgBlinkingExampleG' failed
make: *** [GlgBlinkingExampleG] Error 1
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Looks like you're missing some development tools/libraries. As a start, you can try installing `build-essential`: `sudo apt install build-essential`.

Comment: Hello  @Mr Shunz and Thank you for welcome. I try the same things "sudo apt install build-essential". this give following output.                                                                            root@ubuntu:/home/teqlinux/HMI_SCADA/GenLogic/glg_linux/glg/examples_c_cpp/misc/Blinking# sudo apt install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

Comment: @MrShunz I tried this command before also. This gives following output.

root@ubuntu:/home/teqlinux/HMI_SCADA/GenLogic/glg_linux/glg/examples_c_cpp/misc/Blinking# sudo apt install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.


can you please tell me what is Lib stand for "-lc"?

Comment: @MilavSoni `-lc` links the standard C library `libc`. Please [edit] your question to include the results of `type -a gcc` and `gcc --version`

Comment: @steeldriver Okay thank You

the result of above command is below.

#gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609

# type -a gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: I notice you are running as `root` - which is dangerous and not recommended - is it possible that you accidentally deleted some system files, perhaps including `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so` (or its 32 bit equivalent, if your system is 32 bit)? It should have been installed as a dependency of `build-essential` but you might want to try `apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev`

Comment: okay thank you @steeldriver this is work for me.